# How do you prove the dimension of a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you go about this?

I just need a little nudge in the right direction.

Prove that $v = \{(x,y,z): x + 3y + 5z = 0 \}$ has a dimension of 2.

Comment: You should first mention what you tried.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Do you know the definition of dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical way is to solve for, say $x$ in terms of $y,z$. $x = - 3y - 5z$. Thus $(x,y,z) = (-3y-5z,y,z) = y(-3,1,0) + z(-5,0,1)$. Thus the spanning set is $\{(-3,1,0),(-5,0,1)\}$. this set is also linearly independent, hence the dimension is $2$.

Answer (score 3):

The object in question is certain ordered triples, i.e. a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which has dimension $3$.  Hence it is dimension 0,1,2, or 3.

It's not dimension $3$, since it doesn't contain $(1,0,0)$ but $\mathbb{R}^3$ does.

However, it is dimension at least $2$; you can prove this by finding two linearly independent vectors in the space.  For example, $(3,-1,0)$ and $(5,0,-1)$.

Combining these facts, we conclude that dimension is exactly 2.